# How to write this query in laravel 5

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

I'm experiencing difficulty in writing this query in laravel 5.1,

```
select * from `host_requests` where `host_id` = 5 and (`email` LIKE "%v%" or `request_url` LIKE "%v%")
```

The purpose of this query is to fetch records that are associated with host_id = 5, also email and request_url are optional if they set then LIKE clause should be used. 
I wrote the query in laravel like this

```
$searchname = "v";
$hostid = "5";
$data = HostRequest::where('email', 'LIKE', '%' . $searchname . '%')
                ->where('host_id', $hostid)
                ->orwhere('request_url', 'LIKE', '%' . $searchname . '%')
                ->latest('id')
                ->paginate($size);
```

It is fetching all the records that are also not associated with host_id = 5.

Any help is much appreciated..Thanks

Comment: $searchname = "v";
$hostid = "5";
$data = HostRequest::where('host_id', $hostid)
                ->where('email', 'LIKE', '%' . $searchname . '%')
                ->orwhere('request_url', 'LIKE', '%' . $searchname . '%')
                ->latest('id')
                ->paginate($size);

guess you used orWhere condition at the wrong place if this works

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use `where()` with closure like this:

```
$data = HostRequest::where('host_id', $hostid)
               ->where(function($q) use($searchname) {
                   $q->where('email', 'like', '%'.$searchname.'%')
                     ->orWhere('request_url', 'like', '%'.$searchname.'%');
               })->orderBy('id', 'desc')
               ->paginate($size);
```

Comment: There is a syntax error at "})->orderBy('id', 'desc')"...can you please check it...

Comment: `->orWhere('request_url', 'like', '%'.$searchname.'%');` add`;` after this line.

Comment: @RimonKhan, thanks, fixed. Aamir, what error did you mean?

Comment: When you posted the answer, there was ; (semicolon) missing at line "->orWhere('request_url', 'like', '%'.$searchname.'%');"

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
$data = HostRequest::where(function ($query) use ($searchname) {
    $query->orwhere('email', 'like', '%'.$searchname.'%')
        ->orWhere('request_url', 'like', '%'.$searchname.'%');
    })
    ->where('host_id', $hostid)
    ->latest('host_id')
    ->paginate($size);
```